# How to install catkin correctly

Tags: catkin, ubuntu, ros-indigo, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight dump of the error messages:

```
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ **sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-catkin**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-catkin**
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ **sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python-catkin-pkg-modules (>= 0.4.13) but it is not going to be installed
 python-rosdep : Depends: python-rospkg (>= 1.1.8) but 1.1.4-1 is to be installed
                 Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
 python-rosinstall : Depends: python-vcstools (>= 0.1.38) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: subversion but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: mercurial but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: bzr but it is not going to be installed
 python-rosinstall-generator : Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.7.3) but it is not going to be installed
 python-wstool : Depends: python-vcstools (>= 0.1.38) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: subversion but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mercurial but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: bzr but it is not going to be installed
**E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ **apt --fix-broken install**
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease            
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease          
Hit:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty InRelease                     
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Reading package lists... Done                      
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-catkin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-catkin
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python-catkin-pkg-modules (>= 0.4.13) but it is not going to be installed
 python-rosdep : Depends: python-rospkg (>= 1.1.8) but 1.1.4-1 is to be installed
                 Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
 python-rosinstall : Depends: python-vcstools (>= 0.1.38) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: subversion but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: mercurial but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: bzr but it is not going to be installed
 python-rosinstall-generator : Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.7.3) but it is not going to be installed
 python-wstool : Depends: python-vcstools (>= 0.1.38) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: subversion but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mercurial but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: bzr but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333714/how-to-install-catkin-correctly/) by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-23**:\

> ```
> Hit:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty InRelease
> ```

This seems strange: you have configured `apt` to download package indices for Ubuntu Trusty (ie: `14.04`), but then ask `apt` to `install ros-melodic-catkin`. ROS Melodic is only supported on Ubuntu Bionic (ie: `18.04`) so that cannot work.

You cannot install ROS Indigo packages on 18.04 either.

You've tagged your question with `ubuntu-18.04`.

Can you please clarify *which* version of Ubuntu you are using and which version of ROS you want to install?

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-23**:
Sorry for the confusion.  I have indigo... I also did this:
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/build/build$ **sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-catkin**
[sudo] password for notsotechnical:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-catkin**

notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/build/build$ sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg
[sudo] password for notsotechnical:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-catkin-pkg is already the newest version (0.4.13-100).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python-catkin-pkg-modules (>= 0.4.13) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-23**:
More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067193/how-to-install-catkin-on-a-virtual-machine-ubuntu-18-04

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-23**:
I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual machine

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-23**:\

> More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067193/how-to-install-catkin-on-a-virtual-machine-ubuntu-18-04

you've cross-posted this question to SO within an hour of your post here on ROS Answers?

> Sorry for the confusion. I have indigo...
>
> [..]
>
> I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual machine

Which is it?

ROS Indigo only works on Ubuntu Trusty.
ROS Melodic only works on Ubuntu Bionic.

You cannot have both.

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-23**:
Hey I have melodic

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-24**:
Can you please show us the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`?

> Hey I have melodic

please understand: 'melodic' is the name of a ROS release, not an Ubuntu release. Ubuntu is your OS (ie: a Linux distribution). ROS is "just" a set of programs that run *on top* of your OS. Compare with Windows: if I ask you which Windows version you have installed, you cannot answer with "I have Office 2016".

Now by circumstances, if you say "I have melodic", we can sort-of assume you are running Ubuntu Bionic as your OS. But we need to be sure. So please run the two commands I've asked you to run and show us what the output is.

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-24**:
Hi!  The output outputs of lsb_release -a and uname -a are:

```
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ uname -a
Linux notsotechnical-VirtualBox 5.0.0-27-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 03:00:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The output outputs of lsb_release -a and uname -a are:
>
> ```
> notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ lsb_release -a
>     No LSB modules are available.
>     Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>     Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
>     Release:    18.04
>     Codename:   bionic
>     notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ uname -a
> ```

```
Linux notsotechnical-VirtualBox 5.0.0-27-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 03:00:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So you have Ubuntu Bionic (`18.04`) running in VirtualBox.

First: you cannot install ROS Indigo on Ubuntu Bionic (or at least, not easily, and I would not recommend it if you're just starting out).

So I'll assume you want to install ROS Melodic.

Did you follow the normal [Melodic on Ubuntu installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)? If so, please clarify why `apt` is attempting to download `trusty` package indices as seen in the `apt` output you posted:

> ```
> Hit:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty InRelease
> ```

Did you create this VM yourself? Was it perhaps configured for Trusty+Indigo and have you upgraded it to Ubuntu Bionic?

What is the output of:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

If you've followed a regular install, this file should tell us which version of the package indices you've configured `apt` to download.

Additionally: in an earlier edit you showed this:

> ```
> notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ rosversion -d
> ```

```
Debian
```

this suggests that you have installed -- at one point -- the [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) version of some ROS packages. See #q333234 for a similar question and why you get `Debian` as output.

In order for a regular ROS install to succeed, you'll have to remove those packages from your system first.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-24**:
Hi Thank u!  I think I have installed melodic and catkin, but I'm having trouble creating a string message in a ros package... Does it have anything to do with the Debian packages?
https://answers.ros.org/question/333844/how-to-create-a-ros-package-with-catkin-correctly/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-25**:\

> I think I have installed melodic and catkin

how did you determine this?

I'm also slightly puzzled by your fixation on Catkin specifically. It will be installed as part of a regular ROS install, so no need to install that separately.

> but I'm having trouble creating a string message in a ros package... Does it have anything to do with the Debian packages?

Please don't post questions in comments under (as of yet) unanswered questions.

Let's first make sure you have ROS properly installed.

What is the output of `rosversion -d` now? And do you have files in `/opt/ros/melodic`?

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-26**:
@gvdhoorn . It's a long story... I can't get Ubuntu 18.04 running anymore and I can't fix it... Anyway, I have indigo 64bit now from https://nootrix.com/downloads/#RosVM

I will keep you updated once I get Ubuntu 18.04working again

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-26**:\

> I have indigo 64bit now

please note that both Ubuntu Trusty *and* ROS Indigo are EOL and no longer supported.